# relation ship between power of 2 heap and binomial tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, priority-queue

I am reading binomial trees at following link

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall09/cos441/BQ.pdf

Definition 9.4 A binary tree comprising nodes with keys is said to be left heap ordered if the key in each node is larger than or equal to all the keys in that node’s left subtree (if any).

Definition 9.5 A power-of-2 heap is a left-heap-ordered tree consisting of a root node with an empty right subtree and a complete left subtree. The tree corresponding to a power-of-2 heap by the left-child, right-sibling correspondence is called a binomial tree.

I am tough time in understanding above definition for binomial tree after reading multiple times

The tree corresponding to a power-of-2 heap by the left-child, right-sibling correspondence is called a binomial tree.

Above what does author mean by righ-sibling corresponce in above statement.

It would be good if explained from fig 9.15 view. How author converted power of 2 heap to binomial tree

Answer (score 1):

I know the definition of a binomial heap and still it is really hard to relate it to what the author provides here. Take a look in the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap) and in particular at this image:

[image]

A binomial heap of order n consists of a root node and `n` subtrees that are direct children of the root each one being a valid binomial heap of order 1,2,3, ... n - 1